# Sum of multidimensional Array

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I need to compute the sum of a multidimensional Array. require no extra space, no recursion.

```
class MultiDimensionArray {
    // This is a provided function, Assume it works
    public static Long getValue(int... indexOfDimension) {
        //... 
        return value;
    }
    // lengthOfDeminsion: each dimension's length, assume it is valid: lengthOfDeminsion[i]>0.
    public static Long sum(MultiDimensionArray mArray, int[] lengthOfDeminsion) { 
        ...
        return sum;
    }
```

How to implement the sum() method? it seems like I need to implement a "n level nested loop".

```
for() {
    for () {
        ...  
    }
}
```

I can do this via recursion, but without recursion I really don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: You probably mean constant space-complexity as you will at least need a variable to create the sum!  The template also looks incomplete as there does not seem info about the number of dimensions, only the size of some a-priori known and index dimension. But as this is very broad and looks like homework: what did you try?

Comment: If I'm reading the underspecified code correctly, it's impossible to even call `getValue` without using at least O(n) space (where n is the number of dimensions), because just storing the parameters of the function takes O(n) space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what no extra space means. But my idea is to allocate an n-tuple (n = number dimensions) and a few helper variables.

```
int n = lengthOfDimension.Length;
int[] tuple = new int[n]; // all zeroes
int at = n-2;
Long sum = 0;
do
{
    for (tuple[n-1] = 0; tuple[n-1] < lengthOfDimension[n-1]; tuple[n-1]++)
    {
        sum += getValue(tuple);
    }
    while (at >= 0 && ++tuple[at] == lengthOfDimension[at])
    {
        tuple[at--] = 0;
    }
    if (at >= 0) at = n-2;
}
while (at >= 0);
```

The work horse here is the for loop that iterates over the lowest dimension of the hypercube, using tuple to select the right row.
Subsequently, values in tuple will be incremented until the respective dimension length is hit, where the value is reset to zero and the next higher one (at-1) is incremented. The task is done when tuple[0] has wrapped.